# How could I have known that $s_{2m} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^m}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a sequence $\{s_m\}$ such that $s_1=0$, $s_{2m}=\frac{s_{2m-1}}{2}$ and $s_{2m+1}=\frac{1}{2}+s_{2m}$>

It can be shown using induction that $s_{2m} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^m}$ and $s_{2m-1}=1-\frac{1}{2^m}$

I had no trouble proving these identites were true using induction. However, I was trying to understand how I could have developed this induction hypothesis had I not seen it already.

I computed:

$s_{2m}=\frac{s_{2m-1}}{2}$

$=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{s_{2m-2}}{2}$

$=\frac{1}{4} + \frac{s_{2m-3}}{4}$

$=\frac{3}{8} + \frac{s_{2m-4}}{4}$

$=.....$

$=\frac{7}{16} + \frac{s_{2m-6}}{8}$

There appears to be a pattern that would suggest that $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}s_{2m} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^m}$

And I'm still confused. Help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from $$s_{2m}=\frac14+\frac{s_{2m-2}}2$$

Let $t_m=s_{2m}.$ Then $$t_{m+1}-t_m=\frac{t_m-t_{m-1}}2.\tag{1}$$

Essentially, looking at $t_{m+1}-t_m$ gets rid of that pesky constant in the recursion.

So $$t_{m+1}-t_m=\frac{t_2-t_1}{2^{m-1}}=\frac{1}{2^{m+1}},$$ since $t_1=0, t_2=\frac14.$

So $$\begin{align} 
t_m&=t_1+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(t_{k+1}-t_k)\\&=0+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac1{2^{k+1}}\\&=\frac14\cdot\frac{1-\left(\frac12\right)^{m-1}}{1-\frac12}\\&=\frac12\left(1-\frac1{2^{m-1}}\right)\\&=\frac12-\frac1{2^m}\end{align} $$

---

You could also start from $(1)$ and get the linear recurrence:

$$t_{m+1}=\frac32t_m-\frac12t_{m-1}.$$ If you now your linear recurrences, there is a general approach to find a closed formula, and since $x^2=\frac32x-\frac12$ has roots $x=1,1/2,$ the general solution is $t_m=a\cdot 1^m+\frac b{2^m},$ for some constants $a,b.$

Using $t_1=0, t_2=\frac14,$ we get $a=1/2,b=-1.$

---

In reality, you could have seen this all from the recurrence $t_{m+1}=\frac1{4}+\frac{t_m}2$ with a little trial and error.

$$\begin{align}
t_2&=\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2^2},\\t_3&=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{t_2}{2}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}.\\
t_4&=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{t_3}{2}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac1{2^4}\\\cdots\\
t_{m}&=\frac{1}4+\frac{t_{m-1}}{2}=\sum_{k=2}^{m}\frac{1}{2^k}\end{align}$$

The last is just a geometric series with ration $\frac{1}2,$ initial term $\frac14$ and $m-1$ terms.

Answer (score 0):

Computing $s_{2m}$ in terms of $s_{2m-1},s_{2m-2},s_{2m-3}$ is just sort of "extending" the given recurrence to a higher-order recurrence.  IMHO this is unlikely to help (though I wouldn't rule it out entirely).  Better idea would be to compute a few terms from the beginning:
$$0\,,\ 0\,,\ \frac12\,,\ \frac14\,,\ \frac34\,,\ \frac38\,,\ \frac78\,,\ \frac7{16}\,,\ \frac{15}{16}\,,\ldots\ .$$
There are a number of clear patterns here, especially if you look at the numerators and denominators separately.  Even more so if you rewrite the first two terms:
$$\frac01\,,\ \frac02\,,\ \frac12\,,\ \frac14\,,\ \frac34\,,\ \frac38\,,\ \frac78\,,\ \frac7{16}\,,\ \frac{15}{16}\,,\ldots\ .$$
Then it seems like a pretty safe guess that numerators and denominators each occur in pairs.  So, look at every second term:
$$\frac01\,,\ \frac12\,,\ \frac34\,,\ \frac78\,,\ \frac{15}{16}\,,\ldots\ .$$
Looks like it's
$$s_{2m-1}=1-\frac1{2^{m-1}}\ ,$$
from which $s_{2m}$ is also easy to guess.

BTW it looks like you did not carefully check the basis of your induction.  (Or there is a typo in your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $s_{2m}=\frac {s_{2m-1}}2$ with $s_1=s_2=0$, it suffices to find $s_{2m-1}.$ Note that $$s_{2m+1}=\frac 12+\frac 12 s_{2m-1},$$ so $s_{2m+1}$ is obtained as a binary $$(0.1+0.1\times s_{2m-1})_2,$$ namely $$s_1=0,s_3=(0.1+0.1\times 0)_2=(0.1)_2$$
$$s_5=(0.1+0.1\times 0.1)_2=(0.11)_2,~{\rm etc.}$$ By induction, $$s_{2m+1}=(0.11\cdots 1)_2~~~~(m~1’s),m\geq 0,$$ hence $$s_{2m+1}=(0.11\cdots 1+0.00\cdots 1)_2-(0.00\cdots 1)_2$$
$$=1-\frac 1{2^m},m\geq 0,$$ so $s_{2m-1}=1-\frac 1{2^{m-1}},m\geq 1.$ Now $$s_{2m}=\frac {s_{2m-1}}2=\frac 12\left(1-\frac 1{2^{m-1}}\right)=\frac 1 2-\frac 1{2^m}.$$